# 32kHz crystal long start time on 10% of PCBs we order

Tags: crystal, msp430

We have a PCB with a TI MSP430FR2311. On approx. 10% of the PCBs we order we notice that the crystal startup time reaches several seconds or doesn't start to oscillate at all.

I assume this issue is related to the PCB layout and/or wrong capacitor selection. Maybe somebody notices something wrong...

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Crystal: [Epson Q13FC1350000400](https://support.epson.biz/td/api/doc_check.php?mode=dl&lang=en&Parts=Q13FC13500004) (same as used in some TI development boards), 12.5 pF.

Caps: [Yageo CC0402JRNPO9BN220](https://www.yageo.com/upload/media/product/productsearch/datasheet/mlcc/UPY-GP_NP0_16V-to-50V_18.pdf)

Layout:

[image: PCB layout]

All suggestions are welcome! Thanks.

---

***Update #1***

I've received many suggestions, a recap:

1. A bad batch - possible, altough PCBs are all from the same batch
2. Drive strength possibly too high - very possible, but lower drive strengths did not solve the issue. TODO: test again on brand-new PCB.
3. Capacitance too high (e.g., use 18pF caps instead of 22pF)
4. Do a margin test (add series resistance until faillure)
5. Leakage paths (contimination, coating) - possible, especially since the PCB has conformal coating. I've removed as much coating that I could and cleaned the board (only on 1 PCB). This had no effect.
6. Add isolated ground plane under the crystal
7. Use the XTS toggling technique to reduce start time (as described in [slaa322d](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slaa322)) -> this had a negative effect (no start at all)

Looking into all suggestions will take some time, I'll try to update when I get new results.

---

***Update #2***

I've reviewed the designs of multiple MSP430 launchpads. What I noticed is that, when using 12.5pF crystals, the caps are 12pF, supporting the suggestion that I've selected the wrong caps.

Also, the layouts of the launchpads are quite simple, without ground islands under the crystals (!). For example the [MSP-EXP430FR2433](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430FR2433):

[image]
[image]

And the [MSP-EXP430FR2355](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430FR2355):

[image]
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149086/discussion-on-question-by-juicer-32khz-crystal-long-start-time-on-10-of-pcbs-we); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Loading Cap Size**

Assuming you are correct that the crystal needs a 12.5pF load (which I can't verify from the info in the question), and the MSP equivalent load is 1pF (from the datasheet), then that leaves 11.5pF for the combination of the discrete loading caps + stray capacitance.

A few pF of stray capacitance seems very possible, especially with the Gnd trace/via between the crystal terminals.  That would suggest the load caps should in the range of 10pF-18pF.  Worth swapping on a board that doesn't start and seeing if this helps.

**As noted in the extended question, reference boards with the same crystal are using 12pF load caps, and as later confirmed in comments by the OP, a swap to 12pF did indeed fix the startup issue.**

> I replaced the caps with 12pF caps (Murata 50V C0G), on 2 boards, works like a charm! Crystal starts almost immediately.
> [*Juicer*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/297783/juicer) ([Link to comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/684589/32khz-crystal-long-start-time-on-10-of-pcbs-we-order/684605#comment1824280_684589))

**Margin Test**

Also worth exploring the margin testing procedure described in the [32K app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa322d/slaa322d.pdf), where you add series resistances until the circuit stops oscillating.  Do this on a good board to find out how close to the edge your design is, and then tweak until you get to the suggested margin.

**Leakage Paths**

Putting the above aside, and assuming the design is essentially fine, then from past (painful) experience I suggest you look carefully for flux residue.

As called out in section 5 of the [32KHz app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa322d/slaa322d.pdf) (intro repro'ed below), these oscillators are run at very low power levels, and surface contamination can easily lead to leakage paths which will prevent reliable operation.

With a board which won't start, try giving the area round the crystal, caps and drive pins, a very thorough clean with a flux solvent (2-3 washes with drip dry in between, followed by low temp bake), and then see if the situation has improved.

This specific issue caused me massive problems in the past when we made the move from lead to lead-free, and the increased reflow temperature caused greater flux residue to remain.  In the first batch we did with Pb-free, only 10% of boards started.  Generally fluxes and manufacturing processes are better now, but it remains something to keep an eye on with low power / high impedance circuits.

Section from app note:

> **5 Crystal Oscillator in Production**
>
> In general, it needs to be considered that the 32-kHz crystal oscillator is an ultra-low-power oscillator with
> very low current, in a range significantly below 1 µA. Thus it is critical, for the performance of the oscillator,
> that the PCB assembly process not introduce any materials or residue that would compromise the surface
> insulation resistance and lead to current leakage paths. One common source of residues and unwanted
> materials is the use of "no-clean" flux and the consequent lack of cleaning in the manufacturing process.

Comment: Hmm... This board is coated, and I assume (yes, another assumption ;-)) the board is cleaned thoroughly before the conformal coating is applied. I'll see if I can get the conformal coating specs.

Comment: @Juicer Indeed.  This text from the app note sums it up "While a very effective defense against environmental influences, the use of protective coatings brings back into focus the importance of board cleanliness. Protective coatings introduce reliability risks which are associated with the contamination trapped under the coating into which
moisture can diffuse."

Comment: @juicer Have you tried the "XTS toggling" described in section 5.4 of the app note?  Have you also seen that even in the ideal case, startup times of these low power low frequency parts will typically be in the 1s-4s seconds unless you provoke oscillation?

Comment: I haven't tried, added it to my ever increasing todo list for this issue :D!

Comment: I implemented the XTS toggling; this actually made it worse (no startup at all). I double checked, the XTS bit toggles as explained in slaa322d (and the XTS bit is left at 0 after toggling, which is the low frequency mode)

Comment: I've got the details of the conformal coating (Sirnice CA3002): Dielectric strength (kV/mm): ≥25, Dielectric constant (@100Hz): 2.7, Dielectric loss factor (@100Hz): 0.004, Volume resistivity (Ω·cm): 1.0 x 10^15. But this data is far out of my comfort zone :-D, I trust the manufacturer to choose a decent product. Hope that is the case...

Comment: The conformal coating sounds fine.

Answer (score 4):

From a comment: -

> *MSP430FR2311 has the XT1DRIVE setting, this is set to the highest
> drive strength (which is the default value on wake up)*

32 kHz crystals normally require a drive level that is significantly lower than regular (in-the-MHz-region) crystals. See the mention of 0.5 μW in the [data sheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2018173.pdf): -

[image]

I would expect that the highest drive level will be firmly into the tens of microwatts so, I'd be concerned greatly about this.

I would also want to double-check that the crystal loading capacitor requirement is 12.5 pF and not one of the lower value options given in the data sheet (see picture above). All we have from your question is "FC1350000400" and that doesn't seem to tie-in with the data sheet explanation of the part number.

---

Rough calculation of power dissipated in motional ESR resistance of the above crystal

- Motional resistance between 45 kΩ and 70 kΩ (geometric mean is 56 kΩ)
- Assume 3.3 volt supply
- Assume 2.5 volts p-p applied to crystal (RMS is about 0.9 volts)
- Maybe 1 volt if driven hard with something more like a square wave
- Assume close to series resonant (i.e. impedance dictated by ESR)
- Power is 0.9 × 0.9 ÷ 56000 = 14.46 μW
- It's hard to see that the power is getting down to the required sub μW level

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your deep-dive into this problem! The crystal' full part number is Q13FC1350000400, which is (not very clear from the datasheet) the version with 12.5pF load capacitance. I never realized that it's possible to overdrive the crystal. Do you expect a (too) high drive level will prohibit the crystal from oscillating, reduce life time, or both?

Comment: The MSP430FR231x datasheet says:  For LFXTDRIVE = {3}, 6 pF ≤ CL,eff ≤ 12 pF. Which is the highest setting available. Other settings have a lower maximum CL,eff, so that setting seems to be inline with the recommendation.

Comment: @Arsenal that doesn't mean that you should use the highest drive level. In other words, the crystal used may not be suitable for the IC without an external series resistor. However, if the OP was keen they could calculate the crystal's inductance from the numbers given in the data sheet and, simulate to find the power dissipated. Maybe it's good, maybe not. A quick estimation of power dissipated can be found by using the motional resistance value in the data sheet and, knowing the RMS voltage applied, calculate the power based on it being near-series-resonant.

Comment: @juicer I agree; it's not clear what part you truly have. Maybe look at Mouser or Digi-key to see if they offer the same part with a less ambiguous part number reference. Too high a drive level can certainly damage the crystal and/or reduce its life-span. See also my comment to Arsenal directly above this one. You may be able to put the overdrive worry to bed with a few calculations. And, too high a drive level can cause frequency inaccuracies (a lesser worry).

Comment: @Andyaka overdrive is certainly something to look into, but do you think it could be the cause of the long start time?

Comment: @juicer it could be for sure. If you don't have a high-enough impedance in the output drive circuit (higher impedance equals lower drive power) you may struggle to get the right phase shift through the crystal for several seconds. Can you re-program one that has problems and test this out?

Comment: [Epson](https://www5.epsondevice.com/en/ic_partners/ti/msp430se_ti.html) has some text on this but not specifically for the FR2xxx series but the FR5xx series, where they also use the FC-135 series of oscillators with the highest drive setting, the FR5xx datasheet sounds quite similar but not the same. On that page they don't indicate the use of an additional series resistor. But debugging oscillators without the possibility to change the parts (reduce CL for example because of the layout) will be tricky. Testing drive strengths should be easy though.

Comment: @colintd you should get into the habit of addressing each comment you make so that the recipient is unambiguously clear. Anyway, I would take another look at what you commented because there appears to be an error (series cap).

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the heads up. Will do.  I have deleted and added a correct comment, because as you spotted I didn't mean "series cap"...

Comment: @juicer Also worth trying the procedure detailed in section 4.2 of the 32K app note https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa322d/slaa322d.pdf , of adding series resistors for a working board until the oscillations stop/don't start.  This will allow you to assess the design safety margin, and may highlight the problem.

Comment: @Andyaka I've tested all 4 drive strength settings, this did not have an effect

Comment: @Juicer OK but, it still begs the question: are you driving the crystals too hard? My gut feeling tells me yes. Did you do a test on a brand-new board starting with the lowest power setting possible? I mean, if it was a board that was already run at the higher power level, it may have damaged the crystal.

Comment: @Andyaka I tested on 2 boards that already have the slow start issue. Unfortunately no brand-new boards left to test :-|

Comment: @Juicer is the MSP430FR2311 set to run in "XT1 low frequency" mode?

Comment: @Andyaka yes it is

Answer (score 1):

I assume the capacity is to high. The pin and the PCB trace have about 5pf capacity and 22pf for C9 or C10 gives about 27pf divided by two gives 13,5pf.
Try lower capacitors for C9 and C10.

Answer (score 0):

Just use test board mimicking similar traces and using components that are not working. The result might give you a hint.